# the superlatives/first/second/last/only + noun + to infinitive/V-ing

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

'Practical English Usage' by Swan says:

> Superlatives can be followed by an infinitive structure. The meaning is similar
>   to an identifying relative clause (see 495).
>
> *He's the oldest athlete ever to win an Olympic gold medal.*
>
> (= ... who has ever won ...)
>
> This structure is also common with *first*, *second*, *third* etc, *next*, *last* and *only*.
>
> *Who was the first person to climb Everest without oxygen?*
>
> *The next to arrive was Mrs Patterson.*
>
> *She's the only scientist to have won three Nobel prizes.*

Question #1: Only the last example has the perfect infinitive ("have won"). Can the other examples have the perfect infinitive as follows?

> *He's the oldest athlete ever to **have won** an Olympic gold medal.*
>
> *Who was the first person to **have climbed** Everest without oxygen?*
>
> *The next to **have arrived** was Mrs Patterson.*

Question #2:
Is the infinitive structure merely optional or obligatory?

For example, can you use V-ing instead as follows?

> *He's the oldest athlete ever **winning** an Olympic gold medal.*
>
> *Who was the first person **climbing** Everest without oxygen?*
>
> *The next **arriving** was Mrs Patterson.*
>
> *She's the only scientist **having won** three Nobel prizes.*

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm from the western U.S.

Question #2: None of the examples are appropriate.  the V-ing construction should not be used in this manner.  The construction is used (1) for describing a present-tense but not-yet-complete situation: "Jane is winning the tennis match." and (2) for describing a past-tense conditional: "Jane was winning the tennis match(, until she stumbled)."  The reason I put the condition in parenthesis is that it can be omitted, meaning that something was happening, until some unspecified condition changed that fact.

Question #1: Your first two examples sound normal to my ear.  The third does not.  I would say,

> The next to arrive was Mrs. Patterson.

*This might be a colloquialism on my part.*   But it doesn't sound right.  I believe the reason is that we are talking about one of a series of dependent events that all happened in the past but, from the perspective of the speaker/writer, have not yet completed.  Compare this to the other examples where the event being discussed has completed.

Comment: Thanks. How about this example, then? _Mr. Manafort’s case is separate from the investigation into Russia’s interference in the 2016 election and any ties to the Trump campaign, though **this is the first trial stemming from the investigation of Robert S. Mueller III, the special counsel**._ https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/07/us/politics/manafort-trial-gates-testimony.html

Comment: "stemming from the investigation ..." is an adjective clause modifying "trial."

Comment: How can you differentiate _Who was the first person climbing Everest without oxygen?_ from _this is the first trial stemming from the investigation of Robert S. Mueller III_? Isn't _climbing Everest without oxygen_ an adjective clause modifying "person"?

Comment: As I said in my answer,  "who was the first person climbing Everest without oxygen" is not grammatical ("None of the examples [for Question #2] are appropriate").  A sentence using "climbing" that's similar to the Mueller sentence is, "He was one of many climbing Everest without oxygen."

Comment: I know examples in Question #2 are ungrammatical, and I think they show that you can't have the construction 'the + superlatives/first/second/last/only + noun + V-ing'. And the Mueller sentence seems to be an exception. Why is that?

Comment: An ungrammatical sentence proves nothing.  The tenses are wrong.  If you restate the question "Who ***is*** the first person climbing Everest?" (and ask this while pointing at a picture of a group of people making the climb), the sentence is correct.  The Mueller example uses the present tense.  Your Everest example uses the past tense.  Same problem with the Olympics question due to the use of "ever," which expands the question to all time.  Remove "ever," and it's present tense and correct.  You're missing that fact in your "equation."

Comment: Explaining these sentences based on tenses is really confusing. Let me focus on the Mueller example. Is it okay to use 'to stem' in that NY Times article? _Mr. Manafort’s case is separate from the investigation into Russia’s interference in the 2016 election and any ties to the Trump campaign, though **this is the first trial to stem from the investigation of Robert S. Mueller III**._ If so, is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: You can do that and there's no difference in meaning.  You'll quickly point out that you can do the same with the Everest example, and indeed that works.  But the "Climbing" example does not with the past tense.  I wish English used rock-solid rules that are applicable 100% of the time, but it doesn't.

Comment: Isn't the Everest example the same as the 'climbing' example? Do you mean that the present-tense Everest example works either with 'to climb' or with 'climbing, but that the past-tense Everest example works only with 'to climb' (not with 'climbing')?

Comment: That is Correct.

Comment: Thanks. Does the same 'tense rule' apply to the Mueller example? You seem to have said so, but I'd like you to doublecheck it, because I can't figure out why you can't say _This **was** the first trial **stemming** from the investigation of Robert S. Mueller III._

Comment: "This was..." sounds funny to me. I believe it's related to the fact that "V-ing" is a present-tense continuing-action construction.  Something is happening now and has not yet completed. It assumes more things can come from "V-ing."  To my ear, you can't say "the last trial stemming..." because the action has not completed (no "last" has happened yet).  When you shift to past tense, the action is complete (no longer happening) and nothing more can be expected to come from the action.  This involves (as you ask) words establishing an order.  "I was swimming when..." is a correct construction.

Comment: But a V-ing modifying a nominal doesn't have to denote a 'continuing action'. In the first sentence here, for example, _a V-ing modifying a nominal_ means not "a V-ing that is modifying a nominal" but "a V-ing that modifies a nominal". No?

Comment: Here're some counterexamples: _It was the first trial stemming from the Russia investigation._ https://n.pr/2NFFoL3 // _Manafort's federal conviction was the first trial stemming from charges brought by special counsel Robert Mueller's investigation into Russian interference in the 2016 presidential campaign._ https://cnb.cx/2CRyfno // _Hummer’s was the first trial stemming from federal indictments of 15 officers..._ https://cbsloc.al/2OHECyy

Comment: (\*sigh\*) This conversation has gone on too long.  The existence of bad examples does not make you right and "V-ing" is presently and continuing to modify "a nominal" (despite the incomplete sentence).  It's 2:00 a.m. here.  Have a good night.