# "dinosaurs to fly" vs "flying dinosaurs"

Tags: comparison

I read a passage from an LSAT:

> It seems likely that the **earliest dinosaurs to fly** did so by gliding out of trees rather than, as some scientists think, by lifting off the ground from a running start. Animals gliding from trees are able to fly with very simple wings. Such wings represent evolutionary middle stages toward developing the large wings that we associate with flying dinosaurs.

Could someone explain and parse out this weird subject "the earliest dinosaurs to fly"? Is it a reduced form?

I found this particularly bizarre when reading "flying dinosaur" at the end. It seems the test maker distinguishes between "flying dinosaur" and "dinosaur to fly".

Comment: 'The earliest' is significant. We can use the infinitive ('to') form of a verb when discussing an occasion involving an action - the first man to walk on the moon, the second woman to win a medal, the last boy to get on the bus.

Comment: Why did you post the same question twice on two English language sites? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577685/dinosaurs-to-fly-vs-flying-dinosaurs

Comment: If you had posted on one site and not received any answer, or if the question had been closed then I doubt anyone would object if the OP posted the same or modified version on a different site. But the two Qs are identical, and posted contemporarily.

Comment: What would stop me from paraphrasing [BillJ's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/577686/44619) and posting it here?

Comment: [Pterosaurs were not dinosaurs!](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/why-a-pterosaur-is-not-a-dinosaur-87082921/) The only flying **dinosaurs** were the avian [therapods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theropoda) that still grace our skies and pies.

Answer (score -1):

The infinitive *to fly* is a complement of *earliest*. The infinitive has a subject *dinosaurs*, which is also the word modified by *earliest*. Note that you can use the phrase *earliest to fly* without the stated subject , for example,
*The earliest to fly* were already gone.

Your example has a superlative adjective *earliest*, which identifies the infinitive's subject as unique in some way. Other adjectives making something unique are *first, second, only, last, next* and any superlative ending in *-est*.

The meaning is *the earliest dinosaurs that flew*

This is different than *flying dinosaurs*. The *earliest to fly* are in that class, but they are unique.

This structure is discussed here, with several other examples:
[stackexchange superlative+infinitive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203328/the-superlatives-first-second-last-only-noun-to-infinitive-v-ing)

Comment: I'd say that "the earliest dinosaurs to fly" is a noun phrase in which "to fly" is an infinitival relative clause modifying "dinosaurs". See my answer to the identical question here: [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577685/dinosaurs-to-fly-vs-flying-dinosaurs/577686?noredirect=1#comment1441380_577686)